# Google Apps Script regex returning null (data scraping) (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

**Goal:**
The goal is to grab the shiller PE from this website and to put it in a google sheet that updates every 24 hours.

Website: https://www.gurufocus.com/sector_shiller_pe.php

[The table on the website with "shiller pe" values that needs to be scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIzUk.png)

[Live values needed to be put in this google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eVXG.png)

**Solutions Tried:**

1. **=IMPORTXML("URL","XPATH")**

Tried to use this function in the spreadsheet, but it is just unable to grab the website because the website is too slow

2. **Google Apps Script**

Made this script to grab the HTML of the data and return the shiller value for the Energy sector:

```
function energyFinder() {
  var url = "https://www.gurufocus.com/sector_shiller_pe.php";
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var regex = new RegExp(/\/mq5xwwf">26<\/a><\/b><\/u><\/td><td class="text_center">([0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9])<\/td>/);
  var e = regex.exec(html);
  return e
Logger.log(e)

}
```

But this just returns null. Any solution would help, thanks!

p.s. new to the website so I cannon embed pictures yet, so sorry for that

Comment: Can you add `Logger.log(html)` to ensure that the page is getting downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an issue with the regex itself as there's no quotation mark before `26`.

This should work:

```
\/mq5xwwf?>26<\/a><\/b><\/u><\/td><td class='text_center'>([0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])<\/td>
```

[image]